# I can't connect to mysql in docker from my localhost with DataGrip database client

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, datagrip

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=verysecret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=yii2advanced
      - MYSQL_USER=yii2advanced
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
```

I run it via `docker-compose up -d`. But I can't connect from SQL client to my database (I use DataGrip from JetBrains). Here is my configuration:

[image]

The password of course is `secret`. I have already tried to check allowed hosts for `yii2advanced` user:

[image]

As you can see for my `yii2advanced` connection is allowed from any host. I have tried to change `mysqld.cnf` and set `bind-address    = 0.0.0.0`. Tried to set`bind-address` to `*`. Tried to set not `127.0.0.1` but `172.17.0.1` in the settings of my SQL client. Tried to create manually new one user with full privileges.  No effect. The problem still exists. I can't connect to mysql in the container from my localhost.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, docker-compose create a bridge network that will isolate your application from outside including the localhost.
You need to expose 3306 port from isolated network to localhost.
Try this.

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=verysecret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=yii2advanced
      - MYSQL_USER=yii2advanced
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
    ports:
      - 3306:3306 # <host port>:<container port>
```

Good to read docker network section. https://docs.docker.com/network/